# Anonymous Generics - Where would I use this?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

I recently discovered a trick using casting by example to instantiate a generic with an anonymous type.

http://brendanjerwin.com/blog/2009/03/19/anonymous-generics/

So, its a neat trick, but when would it be used? Any ideas?

Comment: if you still have the original, please include the code in your post because the link is dead

Comment: Link is dead.  Please include the code if you still have it.

Comment: Updated link. Thx for the heads-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary place I use this trick is for creating a collection container for anonymous types.

```
public static List<T> CreateListOfAnonymous<T>(T unused) {
  return new List<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Foo() {
  var list = CreateListOfAnonymous(new { Name = String.Empty, Age = 42 });
  list.Add(new { Name = "foo", Age = 28 });
}
```

Comment: Did I miss something? The second half doesn't seem to use the first half.

Comment: var list = CreateListOfAnonymous(new { name = String.Empty, Age = 42 }};

Comment: @John, you didn't miss anything.  I simply forgot to use it :(